# Syntax error creating a table in my database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, xampp

I'm getting error after trying to create a table for my data base

This is my script

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_role_id` int NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250),
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `dni_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `dni` int NOT NULL,
  `phone` int,
  `address` varchar(250),
  `city` varchar(125),
  `state` varchar(125),
  `country` varchar(32),
  `zip` varchar(32),
  `created_at` datetime,
  `created_by` int,
  `updated_at` datetime,
  `updated_by` int,
  `deleted_at` datetime,
  `deleted_by` int
);
```

I'm getting

```
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near 'CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `u...' on line 2
```

Why is the error generated, and how can I avoid it in the future?

Comment: Works for me. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a47y_xrd).

Comment: What came immediately _before_ `CREATE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Don't use `

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: Backquote is valid MySQL. It's also a markdown meta-character & you didn't properly format your code in a block or with sufficient inline backquotes.

Comment: After deleting the database and recreating it your solution worked. Thanks

Comment: Indent 4 spaces.

Comment: The backtics are optional in this situation.  _This is not the answer to the question._